# A problem from do Carmos differential geometry book

Tags: differential-geometry

A half-line $[0, \infty)$ is perpendicular to a line $E$ and rotates about $E$ from a given initial position while its origin $0$ moves along $E$.

The movement is such that when $[0, \infty)$ has rotated through an angle $\theta$, the origin is at a distance $d = sin^ 2 (\theta/2)$ from its initial position on $E$.

> Verify that by removing the line $E $ from the image of the rotating
>    line we obtain a regular surface. If the movement were such that $d =
>  \sin(\theta /2)$, what else would need to be excluded to have a
>    regular surface?

---

Need your help I have no clue about it.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, we put $E$ as $z$-axis, the initial position as origin, and the half-line $[0,\infty)$ as positive $x$-axis. Then a parametrization for the first case is given by $$(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),\sin^ 2 (\theta/2)),\quad t>0,\theta \in (0,\pi),$$ 
The whole surface can be covered by several such parametrizations.

For the second scenario, we notice that $\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)$ is $2\pi$-periodic ,while $\sin (\theta/2)$ is $4\pi$-periodic. That is, around $\theta=2k\pi$, we have a problem. You can see the following picture[image: Case 2].

Comment: Sorry to bring this back up, but why does theta have to be greater than zero? If it can equal zero, then the regularity condition is not met